# json response in ajax is correct, but content doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that gets called like this:

```
success: function(json) {
        if(json.valid == 1) {

            // some other show/hide here that works correctly
            $("#div-response-" + id).html(json.message);

        }
        else {
            // some other show/hide here that works correctly
            $("#div-response-" + id).html(json.message);
        }
    }
```

and returns the response like this:

```
{"valid":"1","message":"<span class=\"icon color-red\"><\/span>"}
```

or

```
{"valid":"0","message":"<span class=\"icon color-black\"><\/span>"}
```

and the HTML code is:

```
<div id="div-response-<?=$id;?>" data-id="<?=$id;?>"></div>
```

For some reason, I can't figure out why ...everything works correctly up to the point when the div should update the information. It just stays empty.

Comment: use like this json  = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

Comment: Did you debug it with a breakpoint? You can write `debugger;` in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery.parseJSON() function to convert resonse from server to JSON if you are not use type JSON in ajax param.

```
json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server response has a valid JSON header ( that'd be: `header('Content-type: application/json');` ) there's no need for JSON.parse() or $.parseJSON

Also, check the CSS affecting `.icon` and `.color-red` `.color-black` classes on the span. Maybe your code is working but isn't showing anything due to CSS

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to update your div with message in json. Try to use **eval** function. You may also need to parse json

```
success: function(json) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
    if(json.valid == 1) {

        // some other show/hide here that works correctly
        $("#div-response-" + id).html(eval(json.message));

    }
    else {
        // some other show/hide here that works correctly
        $("#div-response-" + id).html(eval(json.message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `dataType` to `json` in your ajax request, and make sure your server produces json data (`content-type` header set to `application/json`)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/something',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.valid == 1) {

            // some other show/hide here that works correctly
            $("#div-response-" + id).html(json.message);

        }
        else {
            // some other show/hide here that works correctly
            $("#div-response-" + id).html(json.message);
        }
    }
});
```